# Snowflake-connector-python fails to install. Returns "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cmake'"

Tags: python, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm trying to install `snowflake-connector-python` using pip, but it's giving me this error stack trace:

```py
            copying pyarrow/tests/parquet/test_metadata.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311/pyarrow/tests/parquet
            copying pyarrow/tests/parquet/test_pandas.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311/pyarrow/tests/parquet
            copying pyarrow/tests/parquet/test_parquet_file.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311/pyarrow/tests/parquet
            copying pyarrow/tests/parquet/test_parquet_writer.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311/pyarrow/tests/parquet
            running build_ext
            creating /private/var/folders/4c/xj1m5wts0xx46bbh5qhhhg4m0000gq/T/pip-install-v4ysgr2_/pyarrow_ae70c3da10594e6eb24b27149ad7d95d/build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311
            -- Running cmake for pyarrow
            cmake -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=/Users/gree030/Workspace/projectName/venv/bin/python -DPython3_EXECUTABLE=/Users/gree030/Workspace/projectName/venv/bin/python "" -DPYARROW_BUILD_CUDA=off -DPYARROW_BUILD_FLIGHT=off -DPYARROW_BUILD_GANDIVA=off -DPYARROW_BUILD_DATASET=off -DPYARROW_BUILD_ORC=off -DPYARROW_BUILD_PARQUET=off -DPYARROW_BUILD_PARQUET_ENCRYPTION=off -DPYARROW_BUILD_PLASMA=off -DPYARROW_BUILD_S3=off -DPYARROW_BUILD_HDFS=off -DPYARROW_USE_TENSORFLOW=off -DPYARROW_BUNDLE_ARROW_CPP=off -DPYARROW_BUNDLE_BOOST=off -DPYARROW_GENERATE_COVERAGE=off -DPYARROW_BOOST_USE_SHARED=on -DPYARROW_PARQUET_USE_SHARED=on -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=release /private/var/folders/4c/xj1m5wts0xx46bbh5qhhhg4m0000gq/T/pip-install-v4ysgr2_/pyarrow_ae70c3da10594e6eb24b27149ad7d95d
            error: command 'cmake' failed: No such file or directory
            [end of output]
      
        note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
        ERROR: Failed building wheel for pyarrow
      Failed to build pyarrow
      ERROR: Could not build wheels for pyarrow, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

Here are my environments:

- Python version: 3.11.1
- pip version: 22.3.1

I tried installing and updating `cmake` but it still gave me this error:

```py
            copying pyarrow/tests/parquet/test_pandas.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311/pyarrow/tests/parquet
            copying pyarrow/tests/parquet/test_parquet_file.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311/pyarrow/tests/parquet
            copying pyarrow/tests/parquet/test_parquet_writer.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311/pyarrow/tests/parquet
            running build_ext
            creating /private/var/folders/4c/xj1m5wts0xx46bbh5qhhhg4m0000gq/T/pip-install-ejkkok_0/pyarrow_e560da15c45d4feeb95b2060af382048/build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311
            -- Running cmake for pyarrow
            cmake -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=/Users/gree030/Workspace/projectName/venv/bin/python -DPython3_EXECUTABLE=/Users/gree030/Workspace/projectName/venv/bin/python "" -DPYARROW_BUILD_CUDA=off -DPYARROW_BUILD_FLIGHT=off -DPYARROW_BUILD_GANDIVA=off -DPYARROW_BUILD_DATASET=off -DPYARROW_BUILD_ORC=off -DPYARROW_BUILD_PARQUET=off -DPYARROW_BUILD_PARQUET_ENCRYPTION=off -DPYARROW_BUILD_PLASMA=off -DPYARROW_BUILD_S3=off -DPYARROW_BUILD_HDFS=off -DPYARROW_USE_TENSORFLOW=off -DPYARROW_BUNDLE_ARROW_CPP=off -DPYARROW_BUNDLE_BOOST=off -DPYARROW_GENERATE_COVERAGE=off -DPYARROW_BOOST_USE_SHARED=on -DPYARROW_PARQUET_USE_SHARED=on -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=release /private/var/folders/4c/xj1m5wts0xx46bbh5qhhhg4m0000gq/T/pip-install-ejkkok_0/pyarrow_e560da15c45d4feeb95b2060af382048
            Traceback (most recent call last):
              File "/Users/gree030/Workspace/projectName/venv/bin/cmake", line 5, in <module>
                from cmake import cmake
            ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cmake'
            error: command '/Users/gree030/Workspace/projectName/venv/bin/cmake' failed with exit code 1
            [end of output]
      
        note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
        ERROR: Failed building wheel for pyarrow
      Failed to build pyarrow
      ERROR: Could not build wheels for pyarrow, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

I also followed the documentation [here](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/python-connector-install.html) and [dependency installment guide here](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/python-connector-install.html#label-python-connector-prerequisites-python-packages) on how to install the connector and downloaded the dependent libraries using:

`pip install -r https://raw.githubusercontent.com/snowflakedb/snowflake-connector-python/main/tested_requirements/requirements_311.reqs`

given that my python version is 3.11.0.

Comment: Use Python3.10, I believe this is a known issue with Python 3.11.

Comment: I believe you might be right

Comment: Python 3.10 triggers errors for me but you lead me in the right direction to help me investigated the issue. 3.9 resolves this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the build dependencies were causing the problem. One of the dependencies `pyarrow` seems to be triggering the error when using python 3.11 at the time of this writing. Downgrading to python version `3.9.16` solved the issue with installing `snowflake-connector-python`.

Comment: Thank you for this!! I've been searching for hours and this was the only thing that worked for me!!